# How to use VBA to browse to file in Access 97?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-97

I'm trying to write a message dialog to prompt the user to point to a TXT file that will be analysed by the program.

How can I make this file explorer prompt in VBA 97?

There's supposed to be a 'openfile' function somewhere but I can't find it. Also the description of the object applications doesn't seem to mention anything about a file prompt. I noticed that in newer versions there's a class called OpenFileDialog and another called FileDialog that seems it would do the trick, but, again, it doesn't seem to be available in Access 97

Comment: I removed '(Classic)' as I'm not sure that designates Access ver. 97 for many of us.  Added the ver. 97 tag.

Comment: Oh! No problem! It's was common to find the reply I was looking for using the expression vba-classic. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the **Common Dialog Control**:

http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0001.htm

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824272